# K3S master does not start due to v1.Event to any object conversion error

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, conversion, master

I'm running k3s 1.26.4 on a small 4 nodes home lab cluster (1 master/worker + 3 workers).
Today, the master node crashed, and a forced reboot was the only solution.
Since then, the master node refuses to start correctly.

In the logs, I can see a lot of v1.Event to  conversion errors. Here is an extract:

```
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:31.123758    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/leases: failed to list *coordination.Lease: converting (v1.Event) to (coordination.Lease): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:31.123782    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (leases.coordination.k8s.io): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *coordination.Lease: converting (v1.Event) to (coordination.Lease): unknown conversion; reinitiali>
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:31.130061    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/endpointslices: failed to list *discovery.EndpointSlice: converting (v1.Event) to (discovery.EndpointSlice): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:31.130084    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (endpointslices.discovery.k8s.io): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *discovery.EndpointSlice: converting (v1.Event) to (discovery.EndpointSlice): unknown convers>
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:31.346605    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/replicasets: failed to list *apps.ReplicaSet: converting (v1.Event) to (apps.ReplicaSet): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:31.346634    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (replicasets.apps): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *apps.ReplicaSet: converting (v1.Event) to (apps.ReplicaSet): unknown conversion; reinitializing...
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:31.899668    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/services/endpoints: failed to list *core.Endpoints: converting (v1.Event) to (core.Endpoints): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:31.899694    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (endpoints): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *core.Endpoints: converting (v1.Event) to (core.Endpoints): unknown conversion; reinitializing...
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:31.969332    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/pods: failed to list *core.Pod: converting (v1.Event) to (core.Pod): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:31 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:31.969396    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (pods): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *core.Pod: converting (v1.Event) to (core.Pod): unknown conversion; reinitializing...
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:32.130119    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/leases: failed to list *coordination.Lease: converting (v1.Event) to (coordination.Lease): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:32.130154    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (leases.coordination.k8s.io): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *coordination.Lease: converting (v1.Event) to (coordination.Lease): unknown conversion; reinitiali>
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:32.136954    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/endpointslices: failed to list *discovery.EndpointSlice: converting (v1.Event) to (discovery.EndpointSlice): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:32.136977    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (endpointslices.discovery.k8s.io): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *discovery.EndpointSlice: converting (v1.Event) to (discovery.EndpointSlice): unknown convers>
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:32.357950    6275 reflector.go:424] storage/cacher.go:/replicasets: failed to list *apps.ReplicaSet: converting (v1.Event) to (apps.ReplicaSet): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:32.358095    6275 cacher.go:450] cacher (replicasets.apps): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *apps.ReplicaSet: converting (v1.Event) to (apps.ReplicaSet): unknown conversion; reinitializing...
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:32.514666    6275 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &errors.errorString{s:"converting (v1.Event) to (core.Pod): unknown conversion"}: converting (v1.Event) to (core.Pod): unkno>
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: W0521 18:37:32.514991    6275 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v1.26.4-k3s1/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Pod: converting (v1.Event) to (core.Pod): unknown conversion
May 21 18:37:32 oc-1 k3s[6275]: E0521 18:37:32.515016    6275 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v1.26.4-k3s1/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: converting (v1.Event) to (core.Pod): unknown conversion
```

Has anyone already had a similar issue, and how you solved it ? I have to admit, I'm a bit lost on what is happening here...